# Migrating Eclipse from Juno to Luna

Tags: eclipse, default-settings

I just upgraded my Ubuntu computer from 12.04 to 14.04, and my Eclipse Juno stopped working (couldn't start). So I decided to download Eclipse Luna. Now I can open Eclipse, but all my projects, settings and plugins are gone.

Is it possible to make Eclipse Luna look just like Juno, i.e. have the same projects in Package Explorer, the same repositories in Git Repositories view and the same plugins?

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall your Juno version download from:
https://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/juno/sr2

instead of using your repository version

Answer (score 0):

You need to be extremely careful.

I'd do like that:

- export your *Preferences* in **Juno**.
- untar your **Luna** onto a new directory
- manually move all the contents in your `$JUNO/plugins/` to `$LUNA/plugins/`
- open **Luna** and:

  1. set a fresh new *workspace* directory > manually move your projects sources to the new workspace > import them as existing projects to see them in your package explorer
  2. look for updates in your plugin (*Help > Check for Updates*) and... update.
  3. import your previously exported Eclipse *preferences*

I am not aware now on how to keep your *Working Sets* in the explorer acroos the upgrade.. that would be nice to keep. You can try to manually move `$JUNO_WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/workingsets.xml` to `$LUNA_WORKSPACE` but it personally here this didn't work out of the box probably because I referenced projects outside of my workspace.